# C# PNG image with transparent zones as Button

Tags: c#, transparency

I'm trying to add a button on top of my form that diffuses a web content. The button should be a round PNG image with some transparent zones (Because of those zones I can't just use GraphicPath circle to manage it).

Of course, my PNG is well-saved with transparent background. In the designer, I put both forecolor and backcolor to transparent. That way, if I delete the image from the button, the button is completely transparent. But with the PNG image assigne it is not.

I found this code:
[C# transparent PNG for buttons, panels...how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458340/c-sharp-transparent-png-for-buttons-panels-how)

My problem is that I can't get to use it. If I just copy it in the namespace of my app, MainForm designer gives me an error:

```
     this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));
```

"Impossible to find the appropriated source for the specified culture".

Do I do it the good way? Will it be enough to just create an instance of this class to get it to work?

Thank you

Comment: I'm a little confused as to your exact problem. Are you experiencing issues with transparency (if so, read up on transparency in GDI and GDI+)...Are you creating your own control to act as a button? Does the button simply not find the resource you are looking for, or other?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "diffuses a web content"?

Comment: I have to put down a PNG image with transparent zones that would act as button. And in the code I found, people say that we can get this result by creating a "custom" control.

Comment: "Web content" is a web page, which content can change in time, that is why I need real transparency, because I can't adjust my background to the color of the page so it acts as "transparent".

Comment: I think you will struggle to do this with Windows Forms. You might want to consider moving to WPF for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Forms are drawn using GDI and GDI+, which are limited in their ability to handle transparency correctly because when GDI was first created, Transparency wasn't a feature that was factored in. That being said, there are some functions that will handle transparency to some extent, like the [AlphaBlend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183351%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

So you're probably wondering "How DO you achieve transparency in Windows Forms?" - Well it's not "true" transparency, more of an afterthought (or hack) to provide "transparency" to GDI (and therefore Windows Forms controls).

This trick is a function as part of UXTheme called [DrawThemeParentBackground](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773306%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which basically looks at the content underneath the control, and draws that to the surface before drawing the child controls.

Try subclass a control and fill its client area with Color.Transparent:

```
public class TestControl : Control
{
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.Transparent);
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        pevent.Graphics.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.Transparent);
    }
}
```

The control draws completely Black, right? That's because GDI doesn't really know what "transparent" is.

So you need to override your OnPaintBackground event and in there you perform the call to DrawThemeParentBackground.

Also, try this:

1. Create a form and set it's background image (use a wallpaper or something)
2. Add a panel to the form, and set it's background to Transparent (it uses DrawThemeParentBackground to do this!)
3. Add your transparent PNG to the panel...the PNG will blend with the background.

Now, as GDI lacks in many features UI developers want, they've all moved over to WPF, which is a completely different beast, but will do what you're asking, without much trouble!

Comment: Thank you. I think I will do it a "restricted" way - I'll give up the inside transparency and just use some Graphic Path class to use a transparent form that only makes appear a circle, in which I put my button.

Comment: @GrigoryKornilov, No problem. Actually I've spent a lot of time investigating what is/isn't possible with Windows Forms, GDI, GDI+, Windows Glass, etc. So if you can update your question and include some pictures of what you are trying to achieve (ideally), what it looks like currently etc. I might be able to help a bit more if I can see the problem visually.